# Onblur event called when modal dialog box is dia

Tags: javascript

I am using a modal dialog box in my javascript that is opening and closing after every specific time . I am also using an onblur event as follows:

```
$(window).blur(function() 
{
   document.title = 'blurred';     
});
```

I noticed that whenever the modal dialog box is shown then the onblur event is getting called always only in the IE11/IE9 browser .

Following is the code for modal pop up

```
function getOverflowStatusOfDatabase()
  {         
                           $("#dialog").dialog({
                                modal: true,
                                title: "Confirm Backup",
                                resizable: false,
                                width: 300,
                                height: 150,
                                open: function (event, ui) {
                                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
                                delay = setTimeout(function () {$("#dialog").dialog("close"); setTimeout(getOverflowStatusOfDatabase,8000);}, 8000);
                                },
                                buttons: {
                                    Ok: function () {
                                        clearTimeout (delay);
                                        $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Ok
                                    },
                                    Cancel: function () {
                                        clearTimeout (delay);    // Close the message box and overwrite using Cancel button 
                                        $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Cancel

                                    }
                                }
                            });  

  }
```

### HTML

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.6.overcast.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <link href="jquery-ui-1.8.6.overcast.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    <script src="../Js/Js_Wrs_OverflowDatabase.js"></script>        

</head>

<body onload="getOverflowStatusOfDatabase();">
    <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
        This dialog will automatically close in 5 seconds.
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Actually I am putting this HTML page & java script  in a remote server.
My remote server is an arm board running Linux and has an IP address . Using the IP address i am accessing the HTML page from my computer and executing it .

Actually the onblur event is not called when I am executing the script in my local PC not in remote server.

So is it true that in some scenario the onblur event is called when a modal pop up is displayed ? Can I prevent it ?

Thanks and Regards,
Sudipto

Comment: Is there any Input element in `$("#dialog")` ?

Comment: @Rayon : Yes i have updated the Question with HTML . Can you please let me know if really modal dialog have a problem with onblur